Pass array string to Fortran module by ctypes
I need to pass an array of strings to Fortran module by ctypes
This is the Python code to pass an array to module Fortran:
import ctypes as ct

files = [b"FILE1.RSX", b"FILE2.RSX"] 
file_ptrs = (ct.c_char_p * len(files))(*files) 
lib2 = ct.CDLL('./reader.so') 
lib2.read_data.argtypes = [ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p)]
lib2.read_data(file_ptrs)

How can I read this array of strings in the Fortran module?
subroutine read_rsx(files) bind(c, name="read_data")
    use iso_c_binding   
    IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
    integer(c_int), value :: numFile
    type(c_ptr), intent(in) :: files(numFile)
...
end subroutine read_data


How would the function know how many strings to process? cause the pointer doesn't have that info. You'll have to either pass it or have some sort of a convention that the last one is NULL.
